# Hashing pairs of integers to array indices?

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, hash

I have a set of sequential, 0-based integers representing vertex indices in a mesh.

Every vertex is connected to at least 2 other vertices, to form edges of the mesh.

Edges are represented by pairs of vertices. So, for example, (0, 2) might be one edge between vertex 0 and 2.

Currently, in order to quickly lookup edges in my mesh, I store my Edge class in a std::unordered_map, and generate hashes as follows:

```
//sorted so (0, 2) and (2, 0) will return same hash
__int64 GetEdgeHash (int vertex1, int vertex2)
{
     return (__int64)min(vertex1, vertex2) * INT_MAX + max(vertex1, vertex2);    
}
```

However, an unordered_map has enough overhead during creation and lookup that it has a noticeable performance impact elsewhere in my code. I'm wondering if there's a way to hash pairs of integer such that each pair corresponds to some index an array whose size is <= numVertices * 2 (since the number of edges in a mesh could never exceed that value). If that were possible, I could just use a normal std::vector to store my edges and processing them would be much faster.

Obviously that's not currently possible since my hash function will return values anywhere from 0 to 4611686016279904256.

A naive approach like:

```
int GetEdgeHash (int vertex1, int vertex2)
{
     return vertex1 + vertex;    
}
```

would satisfy the array size limitation, but obviously results in many collisions.

Is there another way to achieve the same goal?

Comment: What's the exact range your vertices can lie in?

Comment: @SimonKraemer usually 0-65535.

Comment: Did you test whether your hash function has bad collision property ?

Comment: You could use uint16_t then. Two uint16_t values can be stored within a uint32_t value without any loss. You can then use this as an index into your 4GB array. (Assuming an architecture with more than 32 bits and enough RAM, that is).

Comment: ... you could also just use this 32bit value as a collision free hash value for your unorded_map.

Comment: @SimonKraemer The point is to find a solution that can be implemented in an array and is faster than an unordered_map. Initializing a 4GB array would be slower than using an unordered_map and using a 32-bit key would still not solve the problem. It's possible there's no solution to my problem which satisfies my goals...I was mainly just wondering if anyone knows any clever math tricks which might do it.

Comment: Who was talking about a different key? I was suggesting a collision free hashing algorithm with smaller values (32bit instead of 64bit) by changing the data type of vertices to something that still can hold them.

Comment: You won't need to allocate whole 4gb memory if you'll replace `std::vector` with some custom copy-on-write container. I can't suggest any, though.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution could be based on your initial approach, however not using INT_MAX, but the number of existing vertices:

```
uint64_t numberOfVertices;

uint64_t index(uint32_t vertex1, uint32_t vertex2)
{
    return vertex1 * numberOfVertices + vertex2;
}
```

This algorithm is collision free, but requires a vector size of the square of `numberOfVertices`; as is, though, is only applicable if you have a fix (or at least, a maximum) number of vertices.

If the number of vertices might increase beyond the maximum, you could e. g. duplicate the maximum each time it is exceeded, which would, however, require to re-"hash" all your nodes in the vector, i. e. this is an expensive operation and should occur as rarely as possible (duplication of maximum might already make this rare enough...).